# Compatiblity between TeamFoundation Client v10 and v11

Tags: visual-studio, tfs-sdk

I am developing a WPF application which needs to interact with a Team Foundation Server, basically retrieving some workitems. For doing so, I used the TeamFoundation Client assembly v11 which came along Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012. The application works fine for users who have installed Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012. However, the users who only have Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 get an exception saying "TeamFoundation Client v11" is missing. When I changed the TeamFoundation Client assembly to v10 in my application. Now, the users who only have Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012 get an exception saying "TeamFoundation Client v10" is missing.

Would you please let me know if a user has to have the specific version of the Visual Studio Team Studio and the different versions of TeamFoundation Client assemblies are not compatible with each others? or I am making a mistake? 
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

When you're using the TFS Client Object model, then that version of the object model must be installed on the clients machine. Visual Studio 2012 installs and uses the 2012 version of the object model (11.0.0.0) and 2010 uses the 2010 version.

When you want your application to be compatible with Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, then your best bet is to use the TFS 2010 object model. You can download and install the Object Model separately, so that you don't need to install Team Explorer or Visual Studio side by side.

[Installing the TFS Client Object Model 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75) and then installing the [Visual Studio 2010 Forward Compatibility Patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) along side Visual Studio 2012 should allow your 2012 users to connect, as well as the 2010 ones.

You can also install the [TFS Client Object Model 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa) along side VS2010, but since that requires .NET 4.5 installed, you will not be able to serve clients using Windows XP this way.

The final alternative is to build two versions of your application/library, one against the 2010 object model and one against the 2012 version. You could let your installer decide which version to install.

Note: the last scenario can be extended using branching by abstraction and loading the right version of your TFS specific binary at runtime. Using interfaces to abstract that all away.